Only one span element takes CSS rules
Not sure if I'm tired or what. Trying to make setup where there are multiple elements with span class which when hovered upon will make appear some text in a Div. Any tips on how to make this work and maybe even make it more compact. Thanks.


.hide {
    display: none;
 
  min-height: 200px;
}

.hide2 {
    display: none;
  border: solid #ff8900 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
    
.myLINK:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}

.myLINK2:hover + .hide2 {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}
<h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>

<span class="myLINK">Hover over me 1.</span> | <span class="myLINK">Hover over me 2.</span> 
<div class="hide">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
<div class="hide2">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above2.</div>



Need to show text in a div when hovering on top of span/class element.

Change second span tag class name with myLINK2, which is exists in your css but not your html.

Just use .myLINK:hover + .hover-text . Maybe that helps

The + selector Takes the very next element, while ~ takes the next siblings found . That is why only one works. Beside you could use id instead class since you want couples of elements interactions.

Are you stuck with that HTML structure or can you change it?

We now know that a more general problem is to be solved - the texts are to be anywhere in the DOM. But if they are to be shown immediately after the spans a solution to that requires JS. Please describe all the constraints you have and put relevant code structure into your question.

You don't need to repeat the code for each hidden div, just wrap components under single div and apply the CSS


.container {
   display: flex;
   gap: 1rem;
}

.myLink{
  position: relative;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

    
.myLINK:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}
<h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>

<section class='container'>
  <div>
    <span class="myLINK">Hover over me 1.</span>
    <div class="hide">
      I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="myLINK">Hover over me 2.</span> 
    <div class="hide">
      I am shown when someone hovers over the div above2.  
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span class="myLINK">Hover over me 3.</span> 
    <div class="hide">
      I am shown when someone hovers over the div above3.  
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>




It works but breaks the expected layout. That is fine for accordéon layout but not a tab layout. Grid would help here so divs can span the entire row

This doesn't work because I need to place the DIVs in another area of the page other then the links, they are not going to be this close, and they will have different style.

@1advanced you need to make the constraints clear in your question. As it stands with the structure you have shown there is a simple way to do it in CSS, but less so if the texts are elsewhere in the DOM. e.g. are they within a known container?

It's a CSS grid site, yeah they are in containers. There is like 15 items on that page that I need to have text appear upon hover.

You have used + in CSS, which is used for sibling elements.
The correct approach is following, I also have updated class names for ease of understanding:


.hiddenElementOne {
  display: none;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.hiddenElementTwo {
  display: none;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: solid #ff8900 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.firstHover:hover~ .hiddenElementOne {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}

.secondHover:hover~ .hiddenElementTwo {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hover Effect</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>

    <span class="firstHover">Hover over me 1.</span> |
    <span class="secondHover">Hover over me 2.</span>
    <div class="hiddenElementOne">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
    <div class="hiddenElementTwo">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above2.</div>
  </body>
</html>




That is very close to what is needed, however would be nice if only 1 DIV existed where the text changes depending on hover. Also it for some reason seems to work on single HTML page but when I put it on my website it just outputs all of the DIVs and doesn't hide them. Hovering obviously does nothing also. Maybe "~" is conflicting somehow with other elements?

If you wanna use only single div and change text inside it then I think JS is preferred. And when you are adding this code in your website there might be other CSS overlapping it.

References :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.php
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.php
You need to use ~ selector.

NOTE: You forgot to change second span tag class name.



.hide {
  display: none;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.hide2 {
  display: none;
  border: solid #ff8900 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.myLINK:hover ~ div.hide {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}

.myLINK2:hover ~ div.hide2 {
  display: block;
  color: gray;
}
<h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>

<span class="myLINK">Hover over me 1.</span> | <span class="myLINK2">Hover over me 2.</span>
<div class="hide">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
<div class="hide2">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above2.</div>




I'll look at the w3 ref, thx, but your code right now that you posted does not work and it shows only 1 of the variants in the div.

@1advanced, Please edit your question. you have to change second span tag class name with myLINK2, which is exists in your css but not your html code.
